# Mobile hybrid app access database with web service from another country

Tags: cordova

I have a website that be hosted in a web hosting company, the website has database interaction with database server that provided by the hosting company too. I am using web services like RESTful for the website to access and update database.

But currently I'd like to build a hybrid mobile app (with PhoneGap) that reusing the code of my website for front-end development then connect the database that provided by the hosting company from my hybrid mobile app. I was tried to specific my website IP address to connect but seems I failed to do so. The hosting company given me a hosting control panel called cPanel.

how to connect such database server provided by third party with hybrid app? or I must host my own server to allow the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add this plugin to your project : https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-whitelist

When it's installed, add this to your confix.xml :

```
<allow-navigation href="the-url-of-the-webservice/*" />
```

Comment: so this plugin will allow the accessibility for my app to the hosted database? what has to be filled in "the-url-of-the-webservice/*"?

Comment: It's the goal yep. You have to replace this with the url or the ip-adress of the server where your web service is hosted. Like `http://stackoverflowtest/api/` for example

Comment: 1 more doubt, is it something like filling in with "google.com" for example?

Comment: Yep, it's the adress of your server ;)

Comment: A validation would make me happy :)